# How to prevent Event.Resize to trigger twice on displayState change to FULL_SCREEN?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, fullscreen

I have an application with an fullscreen button, when that button is clicked I change the displayState of stage to `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`.

That makes `Event.RESIZE` fire twice if `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`.

The event is only fireing once if i change back to `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL`.

Anyone know a good way to prevent the Event.RESIZE from fireing twice except calling the onResize function directly or implementing a custom event?

Sample code that reproduces the issue:

```
package test
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) 
                this.init();                
            else 
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
            button.mouseEnabled = true;
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doResize);
            button.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x00ff00);
            button.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
            button.graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
            button.graphics.endFill();

            this.addChild(button);
        }

        private function doResize(e:MouseEvent) : void {
            if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;                
            }
            else {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
            }           
        }

        private function onResize(e:Event) : void {
            trace("onResize", stage.displayState);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Further investigation shows that it seems like switching to fullscreen is two steps, first one resize to a `StageDisplayState.NORMAL` and then to `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE`.

Comment: I've just tested your code. It seems OK, onResize is called only once every time the stage changes its state.

Comment: What version of Flash did you target? I have tried 11.0, 10.0 and 9.0 (with normal FULL_SCREEN instead of interactive), all reproduce the same issue for me.

Comment: It was published for FP10. Tested in FP10.2 standalone and 11.1 in the browser.

Comment: That seems to be the answer, my Chrome also only fire one Event.RESIZE while my Debugplayer 11.1 that I use with FlashDevelop behaves incorrect and fire it twice. Thanks a lot. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug limited to the debug player.

Debug version of Flash Player 11.1 reproduces this bug, while the Chrome version 11.2 and browser plugin 11.1 does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean.  For example, make it true in the resize function and check if it's not true to execute it.