# ActionScrip3 Button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, fullscreen

I want to get fullscreen when I push a button.

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

buttonfullscreen.onRelease = function()
{
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: have you checked the instance name on your button?

Answer (score 0):

it really should be

```
   buttonfullscreen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreen); 

     function fullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
   }
```

Comment: try _root.buttonfullscreen

Comment: are you embedding this on html? you might have to change the embed settings

Comment: Where? Here's what I did: I created a rectangle, pass it to a symbol, transform it to a button, select the keygrame, press F9 and put the code.

Comment: did you do    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

and 
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Comment: what version of flash btw?

Comment: check if your flvplayback component is set to fullscreen mode by default it's set to not.

Comment: have a look at this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913432/how-to-prevent-event-resize-to-trigger-twice-on-displaystate-change-to-full-scre